# Combobox saves text to database instead of value

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, data-binding, combobox

I'm using Visual Studio, so at this point I have not written any code, it's all just property settings and drag-n-drop in the GUI. I have a form with several controls bound to a table.  To populate a `ComboBox` on the form , I used the `ComboBox` task panel to bind the options to a view that has two fields (`Type_Num` and `Type_Desc`).

In the properties box for the `ComboBox`, I have my `DisplayMember` set to `Type_Desc` and my `ValueMember` set to `Type_Num`.  When I run the form, the correct values are there in the dropdown, but when I select one and save, it tries to save the `Type_Desc` in the control instead of the `Type_Num`.  What am I missing?

Comment: You should also expand the `(+DataBindings)` prroperty group and check which property is bind. You should bind `SelectedValue`. It seems you have setup dat-binding to `Text` property.

Comment: Also by saying * it tries to save the `Type_Desc`* if you mean it shows `Type_Desc` in the combo box, it's expected. It shows the display member.  But if it saves the text, instead of value, follow what I said in the first comment.

Comment: You first comment did it, thanks.  If you want to submit it as an answer, I'll mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens when you have setup data-binding to `Text` property, while you need to save selected value. You should bind `SelectedValue`.

To change it at designer, expand the `(+DataBindings)` property group and remove data binding from text property and setup data binding to `SelectedValue`:

[image]